# tranform html and css code in bootstrap code

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

im having a issue i want to know how can i make my html and css below be like the bootstrap code that i have posted here to. I have no ideia of how to do it....
My ideia its to do the same navbar but with bootstrap not like it was with the css and html, i hope you can help me guys..
Here is my html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Acessar MMT University</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="icon" href="logo-black.png" type="image/xpng">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
<div id="myModal">
<div class="container" id="container">
<div class="form-container sign-up-container">
<form action="#">
<h1>MMT University</h1>
<span>Se registre para começar</span>
<input type="text" placeholder="Usuário" />
<input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
<input type="password" placeholder="Senha" />
<input type="password" placeholder="Repita a sua senha" />
<button name="submit">Registrar</button>
</form>
</div>
<div class="form-container sign-in-container">
<form action="#">
<h1>Acessar</h1>
<span>Acesse a MMT University</span>
<input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
<input type="password" placeholder="Senha" />
<a href="#">Esqueceu a senha?</a>
<button>Acessar</button>
</form>
</div>
<div class="overlay-container">
<div class="overlay">
<div class="overlay-panel overlay-left">
  <h1>Bem vindo!</h1>
  <p>Para continuar aprendendo, acesse a sua conta!</p>
  <button class="ghost" id="signIn">Sign In</button>
</div>
<div class="overlay-panel overlay-right">
  <h1>MMT University!</h1>
  <p>Se registre para entrar na melhor universidade trading do mundo.</p>
  <button class="ghost" id="signUp">Registre-se</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script src="modal.js"></script>
<button href="#ex1" rel="modal:open" id="myBtn">Acessar</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5vh;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    margin: 20px 0 30px;
}

span {
    font-size: 12px;
}

a {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 15px 0;
}

button {
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(220,52,52);
    background-color: rgb(220,52,52);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 12px 45px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: transform 80ms ease-in;
}

button:active {
    transform: scale(0.95);
}

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

button.ghost {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgb(220,52,52);
}

form {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 50px;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  overflow: auto;
}

input {
    background-color: #eee;
    border: none;
    padding: 12px 15px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.container-form {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25),
    0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 768px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 480px;
}

.form-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.sign-in-container {
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
}

.container.right-panel-active .sign-in-container {
    transform: translateX(100%);
}

.sign-up-container {
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.container.right-panel-active .sign-up-container {
    transform: translateX(100%);
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 5;
    animation: show 0.6s;
}

@keyframes show {
    0%, 49.99% {
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    50%, 100% {
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 5;
    }
}
.close {
  /* Position it in the top right corner outside of the modal */
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  top: 0;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* Close button on hover */
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Add Zoom Animation */
.animate {
  -webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
  animation: animatezoom 0.6s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
  from {-webkit-transform: scale(0)}
  to {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}
}

@keyframes animatezoom {
  from {transform: scale(0)}
  to {transform: scale(1)}
}
.overlay-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 100;
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay-container{
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.overlay {
    background:  #05031b;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #05031b, #05031b);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #05031b, #05031b);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
    left: -100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200%;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay {
    transform: translateX(50%);
}

.overlay-panel {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    /* padding: 0 40px; */
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.overlay-left {
    transform: translateX(-20%);
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay-left {
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.overlay-right {
    right: 0;
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay-right {
    transform: translateX(20%);
}

.social-container {
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.social-container a {
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 5px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}

.modal-container {
  position: fixed;    /* position it so that fills the screen, but doesn't move with it */
  top: 0;             /* position this element at the top...                  */
  left: 0;            /* ...left corner of the page...                        */
  width: 100%;        /* ...and set both the width                            */
  height: 100%;       /* ...and height to 100%, so that the element fills the entire page */
  z-index: 99999;     /* set the z-index to a high enough number so that this element is positioned on top of all other elements */
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.7); /* set the background to black with some transparency, so you can see through it */

  /* The following simply centers the modal within this container */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25),
    0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 768px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 480px;
}
```

And i have this bootstrap code!

```
  <!-- ======= Header ======= -->
  <header id="header" class="fixed-top d-flex align-items-center header-transparent">
    <div class="container d-flex align-items-center">
      <div class="logo mr-auto">
        <h1 class="text-light"><a href="index.html"><span>MMT University</span></a></h1>
        <!-- Uncomment below if you prefer to use an image logo -->
        <!-- <a href="index.html"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="" class="img-fluid"></a>-->
      </div>

      <nav class="nav-menu d-none d-lg-block">
        <ul>
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">Quem somos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#features">Onde atuamos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#servicos">Servicos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#team">Depoimentos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#pricing">Comecando</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contacte-nos</a></li>
            <li><a class="btn-get-started2 scrollto" rel="modal:open" key="login" id="myBtn">Acessar</a></li>



        </ul>
      </nav><!-- .nav-menu -->

    </div>
  </header><!-- End Header -->
```